# topology on rings of quotients e.g. meromorphic functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Suppose that we have a noetherian domain $R$. Then we can construct the ring of fractions by the method described in Goodearl & Warfield. Now suppose that $R$ has a topology. What sort of sensible topologies can we get on the ring of fractions?

For a concrete (even commutative) case, consider the polynomials on $\mathbb{C}$, with quotient ring the meromorphic functions. What topologies do we have here? I assume we have a topology of uniform convergence on compact sets where the denominator does not vanish. However one problem is the creation of what might be called `pole-antipole pairs', where we take (z-1)/(z-a) for a constant $a$ and then vary $a$ near $a=1$ (depending on application, a topology allowing such pair creation might be useful or it might be very bad). This means that a topology on meromorphic functions might not be so obvious as it seems (to me at least). There is always the topology of the set of functions into the compact Riemann sphere.

Apologies for the question which doubtless has some well known solution. I would be very happy if someone could give me some references to look up, especially for the general noncommutative case.

Comment: The ring of fractions of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is the ring of rational functions, not the ring of meromorphic functions.

Comment: The ring of meromorphic functions is the ring of fractions of the ring of holomorphic functions.